# List children of specific page in Xwiki

Tags: xwiki

How do I generate list of children of a specific page? For example, I want to use `{{children/}}` but specify a specific page to list children of.

Answer (score 2):

This is possible with the [Document Tree macro](http://extensions.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/Extension/Document%20Tree%20Macro#HParent-ChildDocumentTree) by specifying the root node. E.g.:

`{{documentTree root="document:xwiki:Sandbox.WebHome" /}}`
will show the children of the Sandbox page

`{{documentTree root="document:.Services.WebHome"/}}`
Assumes a "Services" page is a child of the current and will list its children.

See https://extensions.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/Extension/Document%20Tree%20Macro for more information

Comment: For your example, how did you determine the root should be `document:Xwiki:Sandbox.WebHome`?